# security problems with Java applications

Tags: java, security

I remember in the past there were tons of security concerns with Java applications. After many Java updates, they fixed a lot of bugs and made it more secure but vulnerability still exists. Is there something in particular I can do to enhance my security in my Java web applications?

Comment: Have a look at Waratek

Comment: Yeah. Found it a few minutes ago. Looks interesting

Comment: Weren't the problems mainly with applets? And they were related to the possibility of *malicious applets being able to access things outside the sandbox*, not anything that would affect legitimate applets. (And also not anything that would affect non-applets)

Comment: It wasn't just with applets. It was/is with the JVM itself

Comment: I feel this was a reasonable question to ask. Most people (including me) didn't know about Waratek. Not sure why I am getting the downvotes.

Comment: It's a bad question, as you don't give any of the security concerns.  Java's been secure for over a decade; it's been as secure as any top-tier language since Java 1.1 or so.  You don't give anything to refute, but your premise is bad; this is so broad, it's hard/impossible to answer.

Comment: You may want to ask "what tools can I use to confirm my Java server is secure?" or explicitly call out what the issues with the JVM were.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr Run them on the server, or very short answer - no.

Any complex system has bugs. Operating systems have bugs, physical hardware has bugs and virtual machines have bugs. There really is nothing you (as an application developer) can do to enhance the security of the environment you run on. However, if you really wanted to, you might run your Java environment on a virtual machine. If you disable writes to your hard-drive then it's difficult to image a successful attack vector, but it's always possible someone has an exploit to re-enable it. Basically, you can really only run software from trusted sources.

Comment: Waratek provide a custom JVM and has the necessary tools to dis-allow certain hardware and/or software operations.

Comment: @ScaryWombat That sounds cool, but remember [*Reflections on Trusting Trust*](http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/ken/trust.html).